# Why is my variable not recognised when read into an ordinal model in R

Tags: r, function, paste

I have a variable which is passed to an ordinal model, but when calling the function it states `fm` not found. Sorry I cannot give the whole example, but by inspection, can someone suggest what the issue may be. Is it how I am using the `paste` function?

The code is:

```
inval = paste(colnames(H), collapse = "+")
fm <- as.formula(paste("Damage_new ~", inval))
vals <- clmm2(fm, data = TrainData, random = Compound, Hess = TRUE)
```

> Error in eval(expr, p) : object 'fm' not found

Thank you.

Comment: You don't get any errors by running `fm <- as.formula(paste("Damage_new ~", inval))`?

Comment: no, but when running the function that this is contained in, I get the error.

Comment: This seems odd. "fm" exists in your workspace and is of class "formula" after running `fm <- as.formula(paste("Damage_new ~", inval))`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I used clmm instead which works fine.